# Why does my custom views filter error with 'InvalidArgumentException: The configuration property...'

Tags: views, 9

When I configure the view, it looks proper and works fine until I try to save it, at which point I get this error: `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`  Checking the drupal logs, the error recorded is

| ___ | ___ |
| --- | --- |
| Type | php |
| Date | Tuesday, August 2, 2022 - 12:19 |
| User | {hidden} |
| Location | {hidden} |
| Referrer | {hidden} |
| Message | InvalidArgumentException: The configuration property display.page_2.display_options.filters.newsletter_edition_public_filter.value.edition doesn't exist. in Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement->get() (line 76 of /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Schema/ArrayElement.php). |
| Severity | Error |
| Hostname | 10.0.0.2 |
| Operations |  |

I think I have the views.schema.yml file wrong, but for the life of me cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with it.  I even tried to uninstall and reinstall the module to force the file to load, but to no avail.

**msul_newsletter_helper/config/schema/msul_newsletter_helper.views.schema.yml**:

```yml
views.filter.newsletter_edition_public_filter:
  type: mapping
  label: 'MSUL Newsletter Edition'
  mapping:
    edition:
      type:  sequence
      label: 'Edition(s)'
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Edition'
```

**msul_newsletter_helper/msul_newsletter_helper.module** (abreviated for brevity...showing only the functions that use `edition`:

```php
class NewsletterEditionPublicFilter extends FilterPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
   /* Admin summary makes it nice for editors. */
  public function adminSummary() {
    if (!empty($this->value['edition'])) {
      $returnVal = $this->t('(exposed default): ');
    }
    else {
      $returnVal = '';
    }
    if(is_array($this->value['edition'])){
      return $returnVal.implode(', ', array_map(function ($item) {
          return date('F j, Y',$item);
          }
          ,array_slice($this->value['edition'],0,2,TRUE))).
        (count($this->value['edition'])<=2)?'':', ...';
    }
    else{
      return $returnVal.date('F j, Y',(int)$this->value['edition']);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function valueForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //...
 
    $availableEditions = ['0001'=>'0001']
    //... 

    $nextEdition = strtotime('first monday of this month + 2 days');
    
    $defaultValue = [(string)max(array_keys($availableEditions))];
    $form['value']['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['value']['edition'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Edition(s)',
      '#options' => $availableEditions,
      '#default_value' => $this->value['edition'] ?: $defaultValue,
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
    ];
  }
```

Comment: I have been trying to understand the documentation, but not finding a good explanation that I understand.

Comment: I did a search of the `core` directory for `views.filter.`, and found a number of examples you could look at for direction.

Comment: @Jaypan, thank you, but I have gone through those and that is what got me to where I am.  I am still confused.

Comment: Your type is `type: mapping`, whereas the examples all used a type of `views.filter.[KEY]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave the original question up in case it helps someone, it turns out that there was nothing wrong with the code, but the file path was messed up, I had congif instead of config in the path.